# Table/View 'NEW' does not exist, Derby

Tags: sql, derby

```
Create Trigger AddUserSessionDate AFTER INSERT ON Usersession
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW Mode DB2SQL
UPDATE NEW SET NEW.session_date = CURRENT_DATE;
```

I am trying to create a trigger to fill in the current date every time a row is inserted. I cannot find many other examples other than the three in the Derby [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html#rrefsqlj43125__i1149821). I have modeled this statement after this example

```
CREATE TRIGGER FLIGHTSDELETE3
  AFTER DELETE ON FLIGHTS
  REFERENCING OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
  DELETE FROM FLIGHTAVAILABILITY WHERE FLIGHT_ID = OLD.FLIGHT_ID;
```

but I get

```
Error code 30000, SQL state 42X05: Table/View 'NEW' does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `DEFAULT` instead of trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE Usersession (
  session_date  column_type DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
  ,...
)
```